# find median in O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The question is how we can find the median of a receiving stream of integer values (e.g. for 12, 14, 252, 243, 15 the median is 15) in **O(log N)** where N is number of values. Please note that we have a stream of integer values, hence by receiving each value, we have to re-find the median.

Example:

```
  | Input | median
1 |   12  |   12
2 |   14  |   13 = (12+14)/2
3 |   252 |   14
.
.
.
```

P.S: An example of using this algorithm could be filtering an image.

Comment: Unless the data is sorted and randomly accessible, I'm reasonably certain the best you can hope for is linear complexity.

Comment: Hi Jerry, you are right when we have a list of N values, so in that case we should sort the list( O(N log N)), but as I mentioned the problem here is a little different, we have stream of inputs

Comment: nlogn is the least

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, with the update to the question so the intent is clear (not just find the median, but re-find the median each time you receive a new number), I think there's a way.

I'd start with a pair of heaps: a max-heap and a min-heap. The min-heap will contain the numbers larger than the median, and the max-heap the numbers smaller than the median. When you receive the first number, that's your median. When you receive the second, you insert the smaller of the two into the max-heap, and the larger of the two into the min-heap. The median is then the average of the smallest on the min-heap, and the largest on the max-heap.

Along with the two heaps, you'll want storage for a single integer that will be the current median when you've received an odd number of inputs. You'll populate that fairly simply: if you receive an input with it currently full, you basically sort those two items (the new number and the old median) and insert the smaller into the heap for the smaller items, and larger into the heap for larger items. Your new median will then be the mean of the bases of those two heaps (and you'll mark the other storage location as empty).

When you receive a new number with that empty, you'll compare the new number to the median. If it's between the numbers as the bases of the heaps, it's the new median, and you're done. Otherwise, extract the number from the base that must hold the median (larger numbers if the new number is larger, smaller if it's smaller) and put that into the median spot, then insert the new number into the heap that came from.

At least if memory serves, the extract/insert into a heap should be O(log N). I believe everything else involved should be constant complexity.

Comment: Nice solution.  (I believe extract-min is also O(log N), which does not change the overall compexity.)

Comment: This solution will not work if the buffer for the stream is finite, and you need to remove elements once it is full in the order that it came in. Heaps take O(N) for search. However, you can just use some kind of binary search tree instead of a heap and than all operations will  be O(log(N))

Answer (score 4):

(I assume that you're after an algorithm that, given *n* existing numbers and one new number, will take logarithmic time to find the median of the new collection of *n+1* numbers, so that the total run time for adding *n* numbers will be *O(n lg n)*.)

There is probably a named algorithm for this already, but here's my idea: Maintain a red-black tree into which you insert the numbers as they arrive. In each node, in addition to the number itself and the child/parent pointers, you store an integer that tells the number of nodes that exist below this node (including the node itself, for convenience). I'm quite certain that this information can be updated in logarithmic time on each insert operation, even when tree rotations are required. With this information embedded in the tree, locating the median can be done in logarithmic time if you also keep track of the number of nodes in the tree.

(This might be a slightly too high-level description; let me know if you need more details.)

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was trying to do exactly as you said, but the problem is that to find median only by labeling the number of children of each node is a little difficult

Comment: this is described with full analysis in: Introduction to Algorithms (second edition) - 14.3: Augmenting Data Structures - Interval Trees

Comment: @mahD: If you have, say, 23 elements, the 11th element (when counting from 0) is the median. If the root node's left child says that its subtree contains 9 elements, you know that the median is neither in the left subtree, nor is it the root, so it must be in the right subtree, which contains the 10th to 22nd elements. So, relative to that subtree, you're now looking for the 1st element. Execute this algorithm recursively.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer,another problem here is that, what happen if we have the same value, (e.g. 10 8 7 7 5)

Comment: @mahD: The easiest way to handle duplicate numbers is probably to insert them as new, unique nodes. The standard rule for any kind of binary search tree is that all elements in the left subtree must be less than _or equal to_ the element in the root, so this is perfectly allowable. It is also possible to rather have a `numberOfOccurrences` field in each node, but then the search logic becomes slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

[Hoare's selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm) (aka quickselect) can do this in O(n) average time.

It's basically recursively partitions the data set with a random pivot and checks the appropriate part. 
There is also a [median of medians algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) which has guaranteed O(n) worst time complexity, but for the normal usage it's usually an overkill.

Comment: I think he's looking for an online algorithm which, for each new number that is entered, can produce the median of the new collection of numbers. That can be done faster than with median-select.

Comment: He didn't mention this in the question, if that's the case then interval-trees are perfect... and if he only needs the median of the whole stream then quickselect.