# How to keep track of the median of changing vector of integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Trying to solve a problem at http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/sum-of-medians-1/ and thought to solve it using the multiset as it may contain duplicate values. 
I tried to code as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,k,med_sum=0,p;
  cin>>n;
  multiset<int> m;
  multiset<int>::iterator itr;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>k;
    m.insert(k);
    p=k;
    if(p<=k)
      itr--;
    else
      itr++;
    med_sum+=*itr;
  }
  cout<<med_sum<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
Sample Input:
n=5
10
5
1
2
15
Sample Output: 27
Explanation:
m(1)=median of [10]=10
m(2)=median of [10 5]=5
m(3)=median of [10 5 1]=5
m(4)=median of [10 5 1 2 15]=5
med_sum=10+5+5+2+5=27
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a  sorted ordered container?

Comment: @Carl Norum Yeah that's why I used multiset.

Comment: Multisets aren't ordered, are they?

Comment: @nosid http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/sum-of-medians-1/

Comment: This part doesn't make much sense: `p=k; if(p<=k) ...`

Comment: @CarlNorum I am fairly new to STL and as I know that multiset stores the elements in sorted order allowing duplicates also. Correct me as well if anything going wrong.

Comment: You never initialize `itr`, so its hard to see how that code can work.  It crashes when I run it...

Comment: @CarlNorum: In C++, `std::multiset` is ordered and there's also `std::unordered_multiset`.  A bit strange, but the ordered one came first.

Comment: Use two heaps (priority queues): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10657732/56778

Comment: possible duplicate of [find median in O(log n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842347/find-median-in-olog-n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to maintain two sorted containers, one lower than the median, one greater.

When you find a new element, see what container to insert it into (so that all elements of lower are always less than or equal to all elements of upper), then rebalance counts so that the median is "in the gap" between them.

Yours sort of does this, but defines the lower range to be `[.begin(), it)` and the upper to be `[it, .end())`.  I'd make them separate containers to reduce the amount of state you need to keep in your head to understand the code, unless performance was particularly important.

Maintain two sorted containers, `low` and `high`, with the following invariants:

- `low.size()` is the same as `high.size()` or 1 larger
- Every element of `low` is less than or equal to every element of `high`.
  Then the median of `low` union `high` is `low.last()`.

Assuming you have such a pair of containers, if you wanted to add an element `x`, I would first maintain invariant 2 -- if `low.empty()` or `x <= low.last()`, stick it in `low`, otherwise stick it in `high`.

Next, maintain invariant 1: if `high` has more elements than low, remove the lowest element from `high` and add it to `low`.  If `low` has 2 more elements than `high`, remove the highest element from `low` and add it to `high`.

If we started with a `low` and `high` that obeyed the above two invariants, then after the above steps we still have a `low` and `high` that obeys these two invariants.  And when the above two invariants hold, the median is `low.last()`!

Comment: didn't get properly. Please elaborate little more.

Comment: @SatishPatel done.  Short of writing out the answer for you, and maybe a corner case, the above fully describes what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for replying and explaining the idea.

Comment: This "streaming median" algorithm is correct. I implement it at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/29/streaming-median/) using priority queues as the containers.

Answer (score 3):

What you appear to be trying to do (incorrectly, with your posted code) is keep the values in a multiset with an iterator pointing at the median value, and adjust that pointer each time you add to the set based on whether the value you are adding is above or below the median.

That's a good design and probably the fastest way of solving this problem.  However, it won't work with `std::multiset` because of a limitation of `std::multiset` that causes problems with one crucial corner case -- when the new value being added to the set is equal to the old median, you have no way of knowing whether it was inserted before or after the old median in the multiset.  So you can't know how to adjust the median pointer in that case.

So if you want to solve the problem this way, you'll need to implement your own rbtree or other set abstraction in a way that can give you this crucial piece of information.  Alternately, when inserting a value equal to the old median, you can refind the median from scratch (an expensive operation, but should be rare).

**Edit**

hints for the OP to make the code work with C++11 multisets:

- you need to initialize `itr` when you insert the first value into the multiset
- you only need to adjust `itr` after inserting on the "wrong" side of `itr`.  You can tell which side is "wrong" based on whether the multiset size is odd or even.
- since a value equal to the old median will always be inserted after `itr` you want the test
   `if (k < *itr)` not `<=`

Comment: multiset preserves the order of insertion of equivalent elements (as of C++11)

Comment: @Cubbi: If so, then it could be used in this way, and the OP need only fix his code to initialize/modify `itr` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using a `std::vector`?  Keep the values sorted by inserting where `std::lower_bound` tells you to.

```
    std::vector<int> p;
    int k, med_sum;
    while(cin >> k)
    {
      p.insert(std::lower_bound(p.begin(), p.end(), k), k);
      med_sum += p[p.size()/2];
    }
    std::cout << med_sum << std::endl;
```

**EDIT**
The advantage of using the vector is that the algorithm is very clear and concise (only 3 lines of logic) and the cache locality of the `vector`'s memory and the bulk memory allocations make it at least competitive vs. a `map`/`set` or `list` implementation even if its insertion is `O(n)`.

For comparison I wrote up an (untested) implementation using the `multiset`:

```
    std::multiset<int> p;
    int k, med_sum;
    cin >> med_sum;
    p.insert(med_sum);
    std::multiset<int>::iterator itr = p.begin();
    while(cin >> k)
    {
      if(p.size() % 2 == 0)
      {
         if(k < *itr) ++itr;
      }
      else
      {
         if(k < *itr) --itr;
         else ++itr;
      }
      med_sum += *itr;
    }
    cout << med_sum << endl;
```

The 7 lines of logic is not bad, but it's definitely less clear what is happening and I can't tell just by looking at it if it's right.  Note this algorithm only works in `C++11` where `multimap::insert` inserts duplicate values at the top end of the range (of duplicates).

All in all I think the `vector` implementation is the better way to go, unless necessity and measurements say to go with the `multiset`

Comment: @JimMischel Agreed, the advantage here is that the algorithm takes 3 lines.

Comment: @JimMischel expanded my answer in defense of the `vector` implementation

Comment: @guygreer It works well but I would like to know whether using muktiset is faster or vector? I think multiset would promise to have a great performance.

Comment: @SatishPatel Then implement both methods and run them in larger and larger loops and time how fast each one runs.